# More secure way of sending MySQL commands from a remote server on the command line

Tags: mysql, security, command-line-interface

What is the most secure way of running SQL commands from a web server to a remote MySQL server from the command line. I can think of two ways:

```
mysql --host mysql.mydomain.com --user admin --password the-password-here --execute "SOME SQL"
```

OR:

```
ssh mysql@mysql.mydomain.com 'mysql --user admin --password the-password-here --execute "SOME SQL"'
```

Both of these methods require sending the password on the command line, which worries me. What is the best practice and most secure way of doing this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the credentials in a [`~/.my.cnf`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/option-files.html) that is sufficiently protected:

```
[client]
# The following password will be sent to all standard MySQL clients
password="my_password"
```

Comment: Ah ok. Should I invoke `mysql` over SSH from the web server, that way the connection is encrypted, or is that not needed?

Comment: [Making MySQL Secure Against Attackers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/security-against-attack.html) will give you a comprehensive answer on the subject.

Comment: Yes, when using an options file, you need to use ssh.